# Can I alter data within a mariadb db using mysql-workbench?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am on Ubuntu, remote connecting to a point of sale. I want to update costs of ingredients on our menus.
Can I do this in mysql-workbench?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. I'm logged in now.

Comment: I cannot change values within fields, eg Cost, Price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, yes.

Though it depends on the `GRANT`s for your particular database user. If you can't change the values, then try another database user or create a new user with the correct `GRANT`s.

You should be able to click on a table to list its records (it's the right-most icon when you hover over the table in my MySQL Workbench version), then double-click on the value you want to change, change the value, then hit the 'enter' key on your keyboard, then click the 'Apply' button below the table listing.

Comment: That worked perfectly, so perfectly I feel mildly thick now. Thank you very much

Comment: @empiredave Excellent. Remember to 'accept' my answer as the right one as I live on points. (Or my ego does, anyway.)

Comment: hehe. Had to learn how to 'accept' the answer now :D. Thanks again. My life got tangibly easier in this regard now